# DataContractJsonSerializer deserialize with additional data / unknown types

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm trying to de-serialize a Json string to a c# object. However, the Json data can contain additional data that needs to de-serialize to a dictionary of strings in the object.

What is the most effective way to achieve this?

I've used IExtensibleDataObject, but that just stores the additional data in an ExtensionDataObject, which i cannot read. Are there any alternatives?

Example below :

When the dataContractJsonSerializer encounters unknown data in the Json string, it should  go to the AdditionalData property.

```
Class Person
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Age {get;set;}

   //This should catch any other data in JSON, that is not strictly defined.
   public Dictionary<string,string> AdditionalData {get;set;}
}
```

Json Examples:

```
{"Name" : "John". "Age" : "33" }
{"Name" : "John". "Age" : "33","Address" : "somecity" }
{"Name" : "John". "Age" : "33","Address" : "somecity","Gender" : "M" }
```

Comment: How do you expect it should work for `"Address":{"City":"aaa","Street":"bbb"}`

Comment: Any complex types should be discarded .